# Global auto login doesn't work for StackExchange

Tags: support, auto-login

The auto login feature doesn't log me in to http://stackexchange.com or http://data.stackexchange.com

Is it supposed to?

Answer (score 3):

stackexchange should work, yes, but data.stackexchange doesn't have this yet AFAIK.

But that would be a nice feature to add there.